# Usually in games!

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual

Try to replace the question mark with the help of the clue! The clue will make you understand what those symbols represent. Now you just have to find the pattern!

[image]

(The vertical bars are just there to separate one from the other.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Clue: Rolling a 3d die
>
>  The zigzags connect the pips on a die (1-6)
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  [image]

Comment: Yes, this is correct!