A seemingly pointless puzzle
The answer is a 4-letter word.



Lol look what found https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95381/usually-in-games

@PDT Yes based on that puzzle I made over 4 years ago, however its modified (with lines connecting the pips and no squares/boxes or any other additional info). So made it different.

I am not trying to accuse you that it’s a duplicate I just found this funny when I was looking back at your older puzzles today .

This puzzle is 'pointless' indeed...

 Because it is a depiction of a dot-to-dot across the six faces of a die, moving from one pip (point, spot) to the next!



So the 4-letter answer should probably be what it is 'less'...

 i.e. PIPS!


Correct, nice job!

@Prim3numbah Thanks. My first thought was probably one that most people had - trying to form letters in what we could see (there's a very tempting 'ZZ' in there and what looks like an 'E' to finish) but that first 'sparser' stretch proved difficult to reconcile. It was only when I stopped to wonder what else that last 'E'-like part might resemble that I realised. (I am sure some people will spot it much sooner than I did though!)

Yes, I think so too, that most tried to form letters. I initially actually had 6 boxes but removed them just before posting. Glad I did, would've made it A LOT easier to see what was going on.

@Prim3numbah Agree - boxes would have been an instant giveaway. Just the right level of obfuscation here, if you ask me - a nice lunchtime teaser :)

How did you come up with pips so quick? Wasn't dice itself there to be chosen?

@EtackSxchange Indeed, that was another option I considered, but I figured the main focus of the question wasn't the dice themselves but the pips upon them, making an even more specifically relevant choice.

Not completely pointless. If your 'point' is 21 and you roll this, you take the pot.
